# Upload and download files to MS OneDrive

Tags: java, azure, kotlin, onedrive

I need to upload and download files to OneDrive with silent authorization (no web pages UI to be used). I created a secret key for it in the account cabinet and wrote some code I could find:

```
    fun getGraphClient(): GraphServiceClient<Request> {
        val clientId = "$clientId"
//        val tenantId = "$myId" // or "common" for multi-tenant apps
        val clientSecret = "$clientSecret"
        val scopes = listOf("User.Read", "Files.ReadWrite")

        val credential = ClientSecretCredentialBuilder()
            .clientId(clientId)
            .clientSecret(clientSecret)
            .tenantId(tenantId)
            .build()

        val authProvider = TokenCredentialAuthProvider(scopes, credential)
        val logger = DefaultLogger().apply { loggingLevel = LoggerLevel.DEBUG }

        return GraphServiceClient
            .builder()
            .authenticationProvider(authProvider)
            .logger(logger)
            .buildClient()
    }

    fun send() {
        // Authentication
        val graphClient = getGraphClient()

        // Upload file
        val uploadFile = File("images/img1.webp")
        val driveItem = DriveItem()
        driveItem.name = uploadFile.name
//        driveItem.file = File()

        val uploadResult = graphClient.me().drive().root().children().buildRequest().post(driveItem)
        println("uploadResult:" + uploadResult.id)

        // Download file
        val downloadResult = uploadResult.id?.let {
            graphClient.me().drive().items(it).buildRequest().get()
        }

        val fileContents = downloadResult?.file
        println("downloadResult:" + fileContents?.hashes)
    }

@Test
fun msSend() {
    client.send()
}
```

But I'm getting the non-informative error:

```
com.microsoft.graph.core.ClientException: Error executing the request
    at app//com.microsoft.graph.http.CoreHttpProvider.sendRequestInternal(CoreHttpProvider.java:410)
    at app//com.microsoft.graph.http.CoreHttpProvider.send(CoreHttpProvider.java:225)
    at app//com.microsoft.graph.http.CoreHttpProvider.send(CoreHttpProvider.java:202)
    at app//com.microsoft.graph.http.BaseRequest.send(BaseRequest.java:335)
    at app//com.microsoft.graph.requests.DriveItemRequest.post(DriveItemRequest.java:131)
```

So, how to auth and send requests properly?